# Discarding extra newlines on STDIN in Perl without Term::ReadKey

Tags: perl

I've been digging through search engine results and Stack Overflow trying to solve this problem, and I've tried a dozen different "solutions" to no avail. I cannot use Term::ReadKey, as most solutions suggest, due to limitations of my environment.

The existing Perl script does:

```
my $mode1=<STDIN>;
chomp($mode1);
```

but many of the prompts don't evaluate the input - for example the user could enter an arbitrary string - but the script only chomps the input and then ignores the contents. Several prompts ask for input but pressing [ENTER] without entering input applies default values.

If the user gets impatient while the script is in a blocking function or checks to see if the terminal is responding by pressing [ENTER], those newline characters advance the script inappropriately when the blocking function ends. I don't want to rely on user training instead of automation, and it seems like there must be an easy obvious solution but I can't seem to dig one up.

It isn't originally my script, and its author admits it was quick-and-dirty to begin with.

Comment: I don't understand. How does the script "_buffer_" empty lines and how does it get "_confused_"?  What does it mean that "_prompts ... only check for a newline_"? What do you want the script to do on 'empty ENTER' (empty lines)?

Comment: Could you show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @zdim I think the OP means that users will sometimes just impatiently hit Return a bunch of times while the script is busy, and `<STDIN>` will read those newlines.

Comment: @duskwuff Right, I think I got that part, but I still don't see what the problem is and what they want to happen with that.  Ignore them?  That'd be easy but then what are those "_prompts_" that "_only check for a newline_" anyway?

Comment: "Press [ENTER] to continue."

The script is for testing a linux-based device and I have to wait for the user to check the results on external equipment before continuing.

Comment: how about using input validation to ensure the user has entered the required input?

Comment: Ah, thank you, seems clear now.  But I see a  problem: When an ENTER-only prompt is (further in code) followed by another ENTER-only promtp, how can the script know whether the user hit ENTER multiple times on the first one (so to ignore the extra ones), or duly provided one answer for each?

Comment: For all I can tell, mob's answer deals with the "problem" in my comment above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [4-argument `select` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#select-RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT) is a little cryptic to use, but it can tell you, in many cases, whether there is any unread input waiting on an input filehandle. When it is time for your program to prompt the user for input, you can use `select` to see if there is any extra input on `STDIN`, and clear it before you prompt the user again and ask for additional input.

```
print "Prompt #48: are you tired of answering questions yet? [y/N]";
clearSTDIN();
$ans48 = <STDIN>;
...

sub clearSTDIN {
    my $rin = "";
    vec($rin, fileno(STDIN), 1) = 1;
    my ($found,$left) = select $rin,undef,undef,0;
    while ($found) {
        # $found is non-zero if there is any input waiting on STDIN
        my $waste = <STDIN>;   # consume a line of STDIN
        ($found,$left) = select $rin,undef,undef,0;
    }
    seek STDIN,0,1;   # clears eof flag on STDIN handle
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, first try. I thought it might break the "press Enter to continue" functionality, but it appears to be a perfect fit. 

I'm trying to wrap my head around what it's doing, though. I'm only somewhat familiar with Perl, so your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the easy solution to close `STDIN`?

```
print "Are you sick of answering questions yet? [y/N] ";
$ans = <STDIN>;
if ($ans =~ /^y/i) {
    close STDIN;
    # from now on, further calls to <STDIN> will immediately
    # return  undef  and will assign default values
}
...
```

Comment: There are a lot of "Press [ENTER] to continue" prompts that wouldn't work for, and I'm trying to make sure the user doesn't accidentally skip ten in a row, through impatience or stuck keys or checking if the terminal is responding.